# ASP.NET Core Paypal Implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, paypal, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I try to implement a PayPal cart payment in ASP.NET Core. I have a working example in ASP.NET MVC 5 and I try to convert it to ASP.NET Core but I had no success. The point that I can not resolve is how to get the values that I have to get the transactionID, amount paid and Order ID. In ASP.NET MVC 5 the IPN action is as follows:

```
public ActionResult IPN()
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    var formVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    formVals.Add("cmd", "_notify-validate");

    string response = GetPayPalResponse(formVals, true);

    if (response == "VERIFIED")
    {
        string transactionID = Request["txn_id"];
        string sAmountPaid = Request["mc_gross"];
        string orderID = Request["custom"];
        :
        :
```

In my ASP.NET Core application the IPN action is executed by PayPal and I have a VERIFIED response but I can not get the next three values. I have tried various ways to get these values without success.

My initial approach was the following:

```
string transactionID = Request.Query["txn_id"];
string sAmountPaid = Request.Query["mc_gross"];
string orderID = Request.Query["custom"];
```

Can someone suggest me a way to get these values?

Comment: As far as I know, no official release of a .net core sdk for Paypal. But you can try to visit this repo https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/tree/2.0-beta

Comment: I am not trying to use the paypal sdk. I did the same thing for ASP.NET MVC 5. I manually send data to paypal and I try to get the result back using the IPN method.

Comment: I'm thinking IPN is a post not get, have you tried Request.Form["txn_id"];

Comment: I know that the IPN is post and I have the [HttpPost] over the IPN and I have tried the Request.Form["txn_id"] and I still can not get the value. The best solution that I had until now is to put the variable in the action definition. "public ActionResult IPN(string txn_id)". Using this method I get the value but it does not give VERIFIED response. I guess this way has as a result to change the query values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem and I will post it just in case someone wants to do something similar.

```
[Route("PayPal/IPN")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IPN()
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    PayPalRespond response = GetPayPalResponse();

    if (response.RespondType == RespondTypeEnum.Verified)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(_env.WebRootPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() + "data.txt", $"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} {response.JsonData}." + Environment.NewLine);

        Order order = GetOrder(154);

        //check the amount paid
        if (order.Total  <= response.AmountPaid)
        {
            // IPN Order successfully transacted. Save changes to database

            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            // Amount Paid is incorrect
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Not verified
    }

    return Content("");
}

PayPalRespond GetPayPalResponse()
{
    PayPalRespond output = new PayPalRespond();

    var formVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    formVals.Add("cmd", "_notify-validate");

    string paypalUrl = UseSandbox ? "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" : "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(paypalUrl);

    // Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    byte[] param; 
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(2048))
    {
        Request.Body.CopyTo(ms);
        param = ms.ToArray();
    }

    string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);

    var QueryValues = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(strRequest);

    output.Data = new List<QueryValue>();
    foreach (var item in QueryValues.AllKeys)
    {
        if (item.Equals("txn_id"))
            output.TransactionID = QueryValues[item];
        else if (item.Equals("mc_gross"))
        {
            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Number;

            Decimal amountPaid = 0;
            Decimal.TryParse(QueryValues[item], style, culture, out amountPaid);
            output.AmountPaid = amountPaid;
        }
        else if (item.Equals("custom"))
            output.OrderID = QueryValues[item];

        output.Data.Add(new QueryValue { Name = item, Value = QueryValues[item] });
    }
    output.JsonData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output.Data);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(strRequest);

    foreach (string key in formVals.Keys)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", key, formVals[key]);
    }
    strRequest += sb.ToString();
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

    //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    string response = "";
    using (StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();
        using (StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            response = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    output.RespondType = response.Equals("VERIFIED") ? RespondTypeEnum.Verified : RespondTypeEnum.Invalid;

    return output;
}
```

The enumerator and the classes that you will need are the following:

```
public enum RespondTypeEnum { Verified, Invalid }

public class PayPalRespond
{
    public RespondTypeEnum RespondType { get; set; }
    public List<QueryValue> Data { get; set; }
    public string JsonData { get; set; }
    public string TransactionID { get; set; }
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public Decimal AmountPaid { get; set; }
}

public class QueryValue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```